# Fetch the email name used in Journey via ssjs

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, ssjs, data-views

I am trying to create a cloud page in which when I enter any journeys name with the click of a button I should get the name of all the emails used with that Journey.

Some of these journeys in my account have over 20-30 emails and we’re constantly looking at the journey to see what the latest email in the journeys are.

Is there any way that we can get the data of the emails(Email name) used in the required journey?

Comment: Please update your question to include the code from your CloudPage.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use the REST API, you should be able to collect this information through the following endpoint:

```html
GET /interaction/v1/interactions/{{journeyId}}
Host: {{mySubDomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
```

This endpoint will return all the activities and other correlating information on your specified journey. **[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getInteractionCollection.htm)** is a link to the official docs. Do note that by default it will return the most recent version of the journey, but if you need a specific version, you can also declare that in a parameter of the URL to correctly adjust your response.

This is an abridged version (use `...` to symbolize other data points that I removed) of the JSON response from this endpoint:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "unique-UUID-provided-by-SFMC",
      "key": "a-key-that-is-unique-for-MID",
      "name": "5 days gone by",
      ...,
      "activities": [
        {
          "id": "unique-UUID-provided-by-SFMC",
          "key": "WAIT-2",
          "name": "",
          "description": "",
          "type": "WAIT",
          "arguments": {},
          "configurationArguments": {
            "waitDuration": 1,
            "waitUnit": "DAYS"
          },
          "metaData": {
            "waitType": "duration"
          },
          "schema": {
            "arguments": {
              ...
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "unique-UUID-provided-by-SFMC",
          "key": "EMAILV2-1",
          "name": "FunRun_Email",
          "description": "",
          "type": "EMAILV2",
          "arguments": {},
          "configurationArguments": {},
          "metaData": {},
          "schema": {
              ...
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "triggers": [],
      "goals": [],
      "tags": [
          {"name": "Fun Run"},
          {"name": "5K"}
      ],
      "stats": {
        ...
      },
      "entryMode": "SingleEntryAcrossAllVersions",
      "defaults": {
        "email": [
          ""
        ]
      },
      "executionMode": "Production",
      "status": "Draft",
      "definitionId": "unique-UUID-provided-by-SFMC"
    }
  ]
}
```

The important part for you to concentrate on to get the Email names is the `activities` array.  Inside this it has an object for each activity. Inside these objects, you can find the type of activity (e.g. `EMAILV2`) and the name (e.g. `FunRun_Email`) of the activity.

By iterating through this array, you should be able to gather all the information you need per journey.

If you are new to API calls, I would recommend checking out **[this blog post](https://gortonington.com/introduction-to-making-api-calls-to-sfmc-from-postman/)** (gives basics on setting up an API environment in SFMC) and then **[this post](https://gortonington.com/integration-of-sfmc-with-external-service-via-ssjs-rest-api/)** which can help give insight into how to make API calls inside of SFMC via SSJS.